# Why doesn't the + operator work between multi single line strings?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to concatenate a multi line string with a single line in python and it's giving me an invalid syntax error.

```
 authHeader = '<header></header>'

 reqBody = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">' 
                 + authHeader + 
                '''<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                <GetSnapshotUri xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl"><ProfileToken>quality_h264</ProfileToken></GetSnapshotUri>
                </s:Body>
                </s:Envelope>
                '''
```

Comment: The problem isn't adding single-line and multi-line strings, it's that you're missing any way to tell Python that the logical line is on multiple physical lines...

Comment: Just add `\\` at the end of each line break so Python knows to continue the statement

Comment: @jonrsharpe so how can i do that ?

Comment: In general: parentheses or backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use the `+` operator to concatenate strings you want to spread out over multiple lines for better *readability*. Just do something like this:

```
s = (
    "my very long string"
    "that spans multiple lines"
)
```

The parser will correctly deal with this and it **is** part of the Python grammar ([String Literal Concatentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation). Turning larger strings into sequences of code like this often ends up being far more readable.

For more info, see the Python docs on [Strings](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) which states:

> This feature is particularly useful when you want to break long strings:

```
>>> text = ('Put several strings within parentheses '
            'to have them joined together.')
>>> text
'Put several strings within parentheses to have them joined together.'
```

Comment: But that doesn't work with variables, which is his case